# Integrating Surveyjs with Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-365, surveyjs

I am looking at using Surveyjs as my form collection, and integrating it Microsoft Dynamics CRM, such that it looks like a single application.

Support with integrating surveyjs and Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

I would also like the navigation to be entirely seamless, with dynamics being the backend. And data being reported out to a web app.